# Hard drives unable to rw on ubuntu 17.10 (hard drives mounted at mount point)

Tags: mount, hard-drive, 17.10, fstab

I have recently had this issue which was not present before, I have 2 hard drives which are mounted to mount locations. Today I have noticed that I cannot create folders on these hard drives and I suspect it to be something to do with rw. I have tried to remount the hard drives but no luck.

Here is a snippet of my fstab file below:

/dev/disk/by-uuid/54E897EBE897C99E /mnt/Seagate2TB auto rw,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

/dev/disk/by-uuid/6FE61AA33CE08554 /mnt/6FE61AA33CE08554 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

Please can someone assist me, I have tried to look on google and I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I found a solution. These are the steps I took.

1. List all the mount points `mount -v | grep "^/" | awk '{print "\nPartition identifier: " $1  "\n Mountpoint: "  $3}'`
2. Fix the ntfs partition `sudo ntfsfix Partition Identifier`
3. Unmount the partition `sudo umount Mountpoint`
4. Mount it `sudo ntfs-3g PartitionIdentifier Mountpoint`

Hope this helps!

Comment: You could have add that the problem was a corrupted NTFS partition that *should* have been corrected with Windows tools. `ntfsfix` is quite limited and using it doesn't mean the partition is fine now (it most likely isn't), just that it can be mounted but expect other issues down the road.